# Unity Cardboard App crashes "Unfortuately, AppName has stopped."

Tags: google-project-tango

Creating a basic Cardboard Unity App following this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-cardboard-integration

App loads fine on Unity and build. However, the app crashes without any errors when loading on the Project Tango Tablet.

Error message reads:

> ./adb logcat

```
I/dalvikvm( 4242): Could not find method com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity.showAndroidViewLayer, referenced from method com.projecttango.unityuxhelper.TangoUnityUxHelper$1.run
W/dalvikvm( 4242): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11944: Lcom/google/unity/GoogleUnityActivity;.showAndroidViewLayer (Landroid/view/View;)V
D/dalvikvm( 4242): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0024
D/TangoUnityHelper( 4242): Binding to Tango Android service.
D/AndroidRuntime( 4242): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 4242): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4175bba8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242): Process: com.google.tango.prefab, PID: 4242
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242): Unity version     : 5.6.0b10
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242): Device model      : Google Project Tango Tablet Development Kit
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242): Device fingerprint: google/tango/yellowstone:4.4.2/KOT49H.161129/161129002:user/release-keys
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity.showAndroidViewLayer
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at com.projecttango.unityuxhelper.TangoUnityUxHelper$1.run(TangoUnityUxHelper.java:39)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4242):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  974):   Force finishing activity com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity
I/dalvikvm-heap(  974): Grow heap (frag case) to 26.696MB for 566416-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 398K, 14% free 3400K/3912K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 13ms
W/ActivityManager(  974): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{42185408 u0 com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity t10 f}
W/dalvikvm( 1257): a sleep of (0ms, 0ns) requested: forcing a longer delay
D/dalvikvm( 1257): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6330K, 35% free 13908K/21272K, paused 0ms+7ms, total 30ms
D/dalvikvm( 1257): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
D/dalvikvm( 1257): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2984K, 40% free 12871K/21272K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 22ms
I/ActivityManager(  974): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +1s171ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1257): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.156MB for 468952-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1257): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1235K, 25% free 15971K/21272K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 29ms
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 394K, 14% free 3391K/3912K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 17ms
W/PlatformStatsUtil( 1306): Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
W/ActivityManager(  974): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{42185408 u0 com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity t10 f}
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 391K, 13% free 3386K/3864K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 25ms
E/WifiController(  974): Not handled here 155652
D/WifiController(  974): battery changed pluggedType: 2
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 386K, 13% free 3387K/3864K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 386K, 13% free 3386K/3864K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 38ms
E/WifiController(  974): Not handled here 155652
D/WifiController(  974): battery changed pluggedType: 2
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 13% free 3386K/3864K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 13% free 3386K/3864K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 29ms
E/WifiController(  974): Not handled here 155652
D/WifiController(  974): battery changed pluggedType: 2
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 13% free 3386K/3864K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 22ms
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 13% free 3386K/3864K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 13ms
I/ProcessStatsService(  974): Prepared write state in 30ms
I/EventLogChimeraService( 1306): Aggregate from 1492063872720 (log), 1492063872720 (data)
W/PlatformStatsUtil( 1306): Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
E/WifiController(  974): Not handled here 155652
D/WifiController(  974): battery changed pluggedType: 2
I/PlayCommon( 1529): [102] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(940): Preparing logs for uploading
I/PlayCommon( 1529): [102] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(942): No file ready to send
I/PlayCommon( 1529): [68] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(940): Preparing logs for uploading
I/PlayCommon( 1529): [68] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(942): No file ready to send
D/dalvikvm( 4242): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 13% free 3386K/3864K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 18ms
D/Raydium_ts_main(  246): ## Report rate in 10 seconds =304
I/Process ( 4242): Sending signal. PID: 4242 SIG: 9
W/InputDispatcher(  974): channel '42384d88 com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  974): channel '42384d88 com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/ActivityManager(  974): Process com.google.tango.prefab (pid 4242) has died.
E/Sensors (  974): [nosae] setDelay: 8000000 sec
D/Sensors (  974): Writing packet 54 32 0A 04 40 1F 00 00 74
W/InputDispatcher(  974): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '42384d88 com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)'
I/WindowState(  974): WIN DEATH: Window{42384d88 u0 com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity}
W/WindowManager(  974): Force-removing child win Window{428f0850 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{42384d88 u0 com.google.tango.prefab/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity}
D/Sensors (  974): Writing packet 54 36 0A 00 74
W/WindowManager(  974): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager(  974): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@4232de78 does not exist
W/WindowManager(  974):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7960)
W/WindowManager(  974):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7951)
W/WindowManager(  974):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1047)
W/WindowManager(  974):     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:493)
W/WindowManager(  974):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
I/WindowState(  974): WIN DEATH: null
D/Sensors (  974): Writing packet 54 31 0A 00 74
I/MemoryTrimmer( 2300): Trimming objects from memory, since app is in the background.
E/NvWFDSvc( 1672): onTrimMemory lvl = 5
D/Sensors (  974): Writing packet 54 36 0B 00 74
D/Sensors (  974): Writing packet 54 31 0B 00 74
I/Finsky  ( 1529): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.cb.onTrimMemory(17): Memory trim requested to level 60
D/Sensors (  974): Writing packet 54 36 0C 00 74
D/phs:ipc-loc(  181): Socket 11: hangup from client "com.google.tango.prefab"
D/Sensors (  974): Writing packet 54 31 0C 00 74
E/WifiController(  974): Not handled here 155652
D/WifiController(  974): battery changed pluggedType: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's what it is.
I faced same problem too...
After I've deleted all GoogleVR lib it started to work.
So, my point is, that you can't use Cardbord lib with Unity 5.6.
After you will delete it from your Assets, it would be ok.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using successfully with the Carboard SDK?

Comment: I used the latest 5.5 and everything was OK)
If I answered your question, please mark it as correct.